# "Syntax error: missing )" on jQuery listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why do I get `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` with the following code?:

```
$('#login-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!");  // sanity check
    $('#table').load('http://127.0.0.1:8000/results',function(){
        $('#go_back').remove();
}});
```

Comment: You hasn't ")" in last string after first braket

Comment: If you start indent your code properly, you will see these mistakes right away, and syntax error one get when the syntax is wrong.

Comment: This topic should be close, not make answer for such simple problem! and receive +5 upvote!

Comment: Simple to whom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the ")" at the last line . It should be:

```
$('#login-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!");  // sanity check
    $('#table').load('http://127.0.0.1:8000/results',function(){
    $('#go_back').remove();
    }); // <-- Add it Here!
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Line up your closing brackets and parentheses in the future to minimize the occurrence of these types of mistakes. You are missing what it tells you.

```
$('#login-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!");  // sanity check
    $('#table').load('http://127.0.0.1:8000/results',function(){
        $('#go_back').remove();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#login-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!");  // sanity check
    $('#table').load('http://127.0.0.1:8000/results',function(){
        $('#go_back').remove();

    })});
```

Comment: The OP is asking why.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/jegejuwaku/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks will keep it in mind :)